# COUNT using two (or more) columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Is it possible to perform a count based on a combination of two columns?

I have 3 tables:

student:
`Student id | Student name | Gender | Dob |`

class register: `Student id | Class id`

Both columns make up the composite primary key.

Classes: `Class id | Class name | Class day`

I would like to perform a count of the number of students of each gender in each class.

I came up with this query so far:

```
SELECT class_name AS 'class Name',
  Child_gender AS 'Gender',
  COUNT(student_id) AS 'Count'
FROM student,classRegister,classes
WHERE student.student_id=classRegister.student_id AND
  classRegister.class_id=classes.class_id
GROUP BY class_name,student_gender
ORDER BY class_name;
```

But it seems to be giving me duplicate results for some of the students.

So, can I modify this query to count the number of instances of a combination of the `student_id` and `class_id`?

I'm still very new to MySQL, so I apologise if this is basic for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.class_name AS 'class Name', s.Child_gender AS 'Gender',
       COUNT(s.student_id) AS 'Count'
FROM student s
INNER JOIN classRegister cr ON s.student_id = cr.student_id 
INNER JOIN classes c ON cr.class_id = c.class_id
GROUP BY s.Child_gender, s.class_id, c.class_name
ORDER BY c.class_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.class_name AS 'class Name', s.Child_gender AS 'Gender',
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.student_id) AS 'Count'
FROM student s
INNER JOIN classRegister cr ON s.student_id = cr.student_id 
INNER JOIN classes c ON cr.class_id = c.class_id
GROUP BY c.class_name, s.Child_gender
```

You might be getting the same student multiple times if they have multiple registrations in classRegister. That sounds gross. The DISTINCT in the COUNT should make sure that they are counted only once per class.